# Workaround for not being able to use two types in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, coordinates

I am relatively new to C#. I need to be able to create a multi-dimensional array that holds two different types, array[int, double].  I know arrays do not have this capability and I was told as a workaround I should use a struct, but I do not know how to implement this.

I have an array that holds int values that specify where data crossed each plot on a chart...

```
int[] barHits = { Yminus7Hit, Yminus6Hit, Yminus5Hit, Yminus4Hit, Yminus3Hit, etc.... }
```

And another array that specifies the Y-value of the plot itself...

```
double[] array = {lower6, lower5, lower4, lower3, lower2, etc...
```

I need to combine them in such a way that I can reference the greatest (most recent) int value from the first array and its corresponding double value in the second array.

```
struct coordinates
{
    int x; 
    double y;
}
```

I have been reading on the web about this for the last few hours but honestly it feels like the microsoft docs themselves are written as if I am already a wizard programmer.

Is there a way that I can use the above struct to accomplish my goal?  Is a struct even the right tool to accomplish my goal?

Sorry for the very general nature of my query, like I said, I am new to programming.  I appreciate any help you all can offer.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the structure you're expecting but you could use an array/list of `Tuple`, `ValueTuple`, or `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: If the value in barHits is linked to the value in array maybe you would want to look into C# dictionary, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8. I am not sure if that is the solution you are looking for but might work?

Comment: I did look into using a dictionary, but I need to sort the information to get the largest int value, and dictionaries can't be sorted, so I needed to convert it to a list.  That all compiled, but when I ran it, it failed and told me that the key was already ascribed a value.  The values within barHits are changing all the time, as are the double values.  Is that what the problem was?

Comment: @lunardiplomacy Why do you need to sort the dictionary after the largest int? Can't you just loop through the dictionary and set a variable to `largestInt` if it's the largest value. This way you can just loop through the dictionary and find the largest integer. I am not sure what the use would be in changing key's but changing values should be possible as `myDictionary[myKey] = myNewValue;`.

Comment: You could use a [SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8). You say *"I know arrays do not have this capability"*, but the element types of arrays can be anything. Don't confuse the element type and the type of the indexes who are always `int`. If your ints are relatively small, you can even take the int as index and double as element type.

Comment: @ darclanderSo if I understand correctly, you are saying I should create a dictionary where the Keys are the int (x) values and the Values are the double values.  Then iterate over the dictionary to find the largest Key and then reference its associated Value (the y value/double value)?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes  yes, the int values (YminusHit, Yminus2Hit, etc... ) which are always changing are the index value for the double value I need.  I am trying to read the literature you linked fast enough to respond, but I think I am on the right track now.  Would you be so kind as to provide an example of how this syntax would actually look?

Comment: With this struct, you can define the array as `coordinates[] array = new[] { new coordinates{ x = Yminus7Hit, y = lower6}, new coordinates{ x = Yminus6Hit, y = lower5}, ... };`. But if the `int` values are the index, you can declare the array as `double[] array = new double[N];` and use like `array[Yminus7Hit] = lower6;`

Comment: Once I have established my SortedDictionary<int, double>, I would be able to use openWith[Yhit] to get the double value I need?

Comment: Yes. Also with a simple double array. The difference is that the array has an element at every int (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... N - 1), while the sorted dict has only the entries you added, which works well with sparse indexes.

Comment: Oh, that looks wonderful.  And I would be able to access those elements as I would any other array?  i.e. Array[0,1] or Array.Sort?  Or no

Comment: The indexes of the array are always sorted, since they indicate the (physical) position in the array. Sorting is only necessary if you want the double values to be sorted. The index is not stored in the array. It's only the indication of the location in the array. If not all the array position contain a value, you could also use a nulllable values: `double?[]` and query `if (array[yhit].HasValue) double result = array[yhit].Value;`

Comment: Okay, SE is yelling at me for having a discussion in the comments.  You have been very helpful, Oliver, I think I understand now what I need to do.  Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a object and put this in a list?

```
public class type_xy
{
   private int x;
   private double y;

  public type_xy()
  {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
  }

  public int X_value
  {
    get => x;
    set => x = value;
  }

  public double Y_value
  {
    get => y;
    set => y = value;
  }
}
```

Then in the main code:

```
Ilist<type_xy> Data = new List<type_xy>();
```

To make a new item

```
private void ADD(int x, int y)
{
  type_xy n = new type_xy();

  n.X_value = x;
  n.Y_value = y;

  Data.Add(n);
}
```